# Is it possible to run timer job like run now and get results

Tags: timer-jobs, web-analytics

1. Just added a new Web Analytic service (that's been broken for ever) using [msdn gg266382 article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382.aspx)
2. Made sure everything is enabled and configured for this new web analytic service (and made sure old wa is deleted)
3. Made sure new WA is part of the default app list
4. Now went to different site collections and added stuff here and there for different list (just to generate the usage log, so report can be generated)
5. Ran the jobs in the following order:
   “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import”
   “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing”
   “Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job”
6. All jobs showed "Succeeded"
7. Went back to different site collection's web analytic report section (_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx) and guess what they all are showing ZERO (0).

I'm on this issue last 2 month and haven't been able to rectify the issue. Also, no errors showing in the windows log for the app or wfe servers. No SQL error on the SQL db Server.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have exhausted all possible steps to resolve this issue. Would you please go through this steps again per Brian's blog and see if it's any help?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Julie:

Follow the link Maria Burton Posted and also make sure under Windows Service the "SharePoint trace job" uses Local Service (instead of a service account). And make sure all the servers (app, index, wfe) has it same way.

Always, give it a day to see the outcome. I had similar issues where running timer job would not populate the traffic. But next day I saw report being generated.